# Wwork around max number of nested if statements

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following if statement in cell A1 which checks my cell W7 for values between the specified numbers:

my cell W7 can have a value from as high as 525 to as low as 0:

```
0 - 525
```

The higher the value in my cell W7 the less the value in my cell A1 where my If statement is.

What I have at the moment is a working if statement. This checks my value in the w7 cell upto the amount of 300 which then shows the number 40 in my cell a1.

here is my existing if statement:

```
  =IF(Dashboard!W7=0, 100, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>= 0, Dashboard!W7<50), 90, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=50, Dashboard!W7<100), 80, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=100, Dashboard!W7<150), 70, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=150, Dashboard!W7<200), 60, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=200, Dashboard!W7<250), 50, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=250, Dashboard!W7<300), 40)))))))
```

However, I need to carry on this sequence by adding the rest of my if statements:

```
IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=300, Dashboard!W7<350), 30, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=350, Dashboard!W7<400), 20, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=400, Dashboard!W7<450), 10, IF(AND(Dashboard!W7>=450, Dashboard!W7<525), 0))))
```

the problem I have is when I combine the last of my if statements to my existing if statement, I get a max number of nested if statements reached error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to a [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93).

```
=LOOKUP(Dashboard!W7, {0, 0.01, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 525}, {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, 0})
```

Alternately, you could set up a small rudimentary data table and use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to retrieve the amount. This latter method is particularly preferred if changes to the data to lookup/retrieve occurs often.

**Addendum:**

If the values are not likely to change often, you might try this mathematical pattern method.

```
=MAX(90-INT(Dashboard!W7/50)*10, 0)+NOT(Dashboard!W7)*10
```

Comment: I think it should be `INT(Dashboard!W7/50)*10` in the second solution

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly and well done on such a clean and tidy code, cant thank you enough

Comment: @user3964075 - Thanks for catching that. The sample data I tested against wasn't diverse enough to show the difference and I out-smarted myself.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is the CASE statement.  You can specify discreet values, or anything in a range.  This example is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx):

```
Dim number As Integer = 8
Select Case number
    Case 1 To 5
        Debug.WriteLine("Between 1 and 5, inclusive")
        ' The following is the only Case clause that evaluates to True. 
    Case 6, 7, 8
        Debug.WriteLine("Between 6 and 8, inclusive")
    Case 9 To 10
        Debug.WriteLine("Equal to 9 or 10")
    Case Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Not between 1 and 10, inclusive")
End Select
```

The answer above using Lookup is fine; SELECT CASE is just another tool for the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach is to use a conditional `Choose`, which works a bit like a `Select Case` statememnt in VBA. The only issue is your criteria need to be mutually exclusive (or you'll get some strange results).

Syntax is:

```
Choose(
    (1 * Test1) + (2 * Test2) + (3 * Test3) + ... + (254 * Test4),
    Result1, Result2, Result3, .... ,Result254
)
```

Results can be anything - including further tests, and as far as I can tell, will be evaluated lazily.

Just be careful - if Test1 and Test2 are both true, then you'll get the result for Test3 (because `(1 * 1) + (2 * 1) + (3 * 0) = 3`)